# Default option in select

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this very simple select element:

```
<label>Items per page</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm w25" ng-model="itemsPerPage">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
```

with controller:

```
 $scope.itemsPerPage = 5; // default value
```

But the default value is a blank option and the default value attempt doesn't do anything.

How do I make the value 5 the default?

Comment: Creates a question, doesnt accept answer, deletes account :(

Answer (score 2):

Angular is probably converting that value to a string, so do:

```
$scope.itemsPerPage = "5";
```